# problem in applying tf.nn.dropout() with 3D-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to apply tf.nn.dropout with 3D-CNN layer

but I faced error `"ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor."`

the code is

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=Xshape)

model1 = layers.Conv3D(64, input_shape=Xshape, kernel_size=(7, 7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')

y=model1(inputs)

weights_as_numpy = model1.get_weights()

x=tf.nn.dropout(weights_as_numpy, rate = 0.5, seed = 1)
```

then, I used `data_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(weights_as_numpy)`

but I faced another error which is: `ValueError: all scalar values must have the same nesting depth`

can you please help me?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are you applying dropout on a list of weights? This is incorrect usage since it needs a single tensor, not a list of tensors (and it's a very unusual thing to do).

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I apply it on weights because I want to use dropout as DropConnect function. if you have answer please help me...